# CSS 360° line rotation fail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to rotate a line with the css transfrom propterty based on the position of the element. (DEMO: http://www.nimmi.de/tools) DESCRIPTION: click on a red circle and then on another to connect them both with each other. Then press the left mouse button and hold it over the container and drag it around. Your will see that the line buggs after a certain angle. I don't know why, here is my code for the rotation:

```
function lineTo(x1,y1,x2,y2,line){
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1,2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;

    line.style.transform = "rotate("+ angle + "deg)";
    line.style.width = dist+"px";
}
```

`x1/x2/y1/y2` are just the coords of the two points where the line is connected to. `line` is just a HTML `hr` element with the following styles:

```
        .line {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin-top: calc(50% - 1px);
            margin-left: calc(50% - 1px);
            width: 0px;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

i don't understand why this bug appears, where is the mistake !?

Answer (score 1):

atan is not always the correct mathematical function to use. When the variables x and y end up being negative the error appears.

Try changing the function to calculate the correct function given the current inputs.

Answer (score 1):

`lineTo` seems to be fine with a full 360 rotation. I reimplemented it doing a full 360 with no issues: https://jsfiddle.net/3a3pgn39/ (I cleaned it up for my own purposes but, algorithmically, it's the same). I also tested it will all 9 possible permutations for origin values `(zero, negative, positive)^2` and it didn't seem to matter.

With that in mind, maybe your errors come from another source? When dealing with mouse events, it's pretty common to run into screen vs. document space issues etc.

EDIT: P.S. Doing this kind of stuff entirely with bare JavaScript and DOM manipulation might be making the solution a bit more complicated than it needs to be though. You might be better off, in the long run, checking out using `<canvas>` to draw bits of the UI rather than trying to do all your manipulations *via* `CSS3` transforms. It will get v.messy with bigger applications otherwise.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. Second i dont work with mouse events directly i have a function called getXY where i pass in an element and the function returns a x and y value `function getXY(obj){ return {x:obj.getBoundingClientRect().left, y: obj.getBoundingClientRect().top};}`. This can be the only error source because the lineTo function just get called with the getXY function of the both elements connected by the line  `lineTo(getXY(elm).x,getXY(elm).y,getXY(connected_elm).x,getXY(connected_elm).y,elm);`

Comment: I mean, maybe the implementation I pasted somehow mis-performs in your application but it seems to be doing a full 360 deg draw without glitching. I'm easily confused by these types of graphical errors. To compensate for that, I use a JavaScript debugger that shows variable values, stack trace, etc. I'd reccomend using one (google) if you regularly have these kinds of weird issues.

Comment: ok i try it now with the buildin js chrome debugger with breakpoints. Thanks for your assistance.